# PHP: Dynamic dropdown cascade to select directory and then folder

Tags: php, html, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I've only used PHP with MySQL before, and I'm finding myself stuck on how to work without a database! I really appreciate any help.

I would like to create two dynamic dropdowns. The first to select a directory, and the second, to pick a file in the selected directory.

Here's the code I'm currently using to select a directory, but I'm stuck on what to do next.

This function works to pull up the directories. I want to pass the selected directory on to the next dropdown and have the next dropdown display a list of files in the selected directory.

```
<select name="Dirs">
<option value="" selected="selected">Lab</option>
<?php
$dirs = glob("/var/www/html/blast/labs/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
foreach($dirs as $val){
echo '<option value="'.basename($val).'">'.basename($val)."</option>\n";
}
?>
</select>
```

The solution:

I added two drop-downs using this script on the main page:

```
<select id="Files" name="Files">
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){ 
  $("#Dirs").on('change', function(){
     var Dir = $(this).val();
 //Make an ajax call 
     $( "#Files" ).html( '<option>Loading...</option>' );
     $.get( "listfiles.php?Dirs=" + encodeURIComponent(Dir), function( data ) {
       //Update the files dropdown 
       $( "#Files" ).html( data ); 
     });
  });
});
</script>
```

And created a file called "listfiles.php" that included this php script:

```
$folder = $_GET['Dirs'];
if(!file_exists($folder)) {
exit('File Not Found');
}

$out = '';

function only_files($file) { $idx = strlen($file) - 1;
return substr($file, $idx) != '/';
}

$files = array_filter(glob($folder . "/*", GLOB_MARK), 'only_files');

foreach($files as $val){
$out .= '<option value="'.$val.'">'.basename($val)."</option>\n";
}

//Output the file options
exit($out);
```

Comment: i dont see what the lack of a db has to do with this

Comment: Well, without queries, I'm just not sure how it works. Do I still use post? Can I pass $val on to the next drop-down? So this function works to pull up the directories. I want to pass the selected directory on to the next dropdown and have the next dropdown display a list of files in the selected directory.

Comment: not understanding what you're not understanding ;(

Comment: Hi @Dagon. Thanks for following up. This dropdown above works great. How do I grab the directory that the user selected from the dropdown above and display a second drop-down menu of all the files that were in the selected directory?

Comment: it either has to be submitted to the server in a form (post\get) or you use ajax

Comment: Consider using Ajax for sure. It's most likely your best bet with such a simple function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery ajax to populate the files dropdown, here is an example

```
<select id="dirs" name="Dirs">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Lab</option>
  <?php
     $dirs = glob("/var/www/html/blast/labs/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
        foreach($dirs as $val){
           echo '<option value="'.$val.'">'.basename($val)."</option>\n";
        }
  ?>
</select>

<select id="files" name="mFiles">

</select>
```

you will need a file to handle ajax calls or simply put below code at beginning of your file

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
 /* AJAX check  */
 if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&
    strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {

    //Check for passed dir exist 
    $folder = $_GET['Dirs'];

    if(!file_exists($folder)) {
      exit('Folder Not Found');
    }

    $out = '';

    $files = array_filter(glob($folder.'/*'), 'is_file');
      foreach($files as $val){
          $out .= '<option value="'.$val.'">'.basename($val)."</option>\n";
      }

    //Output the file options
    exit($out);

 }
```

jQuery code to make ajax calls and update the files option

```
$(function(){ 
   $("#dirs").on('change', function(){
      var Dir = $(this).val();
      //Make an ajax call 
      $( "#files" ).html( '<option>Loading...</option>' );
      $.get( "ajax.php?Dirs=" + encodeURIComponent(Dir), function( data ) {
        //Update the files dropdown 
        $( "#files" ).html( data ); 
      });
   });
});
```

Give it a try, am sure it will help you

Comment: Thank you so much for getting me off on the right start. I will post above what finally worked. I really appreciate the help!